# How to compare two values in protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor

code to get the values

```
var archived_projects_before = element.all(by.css('a[ng-click="setCurrentGroup(tab)"]')).get(6).getText().then(function(text){console.log(text);})

var archived_projects_before = element.all(by.css('a[ng-click="setCurrentGroupproject(tab)"]')).get(6).getText().then(function(text){console.log(text);})
```

using this code am getting two values i.e:

```
5,
6
```

Problem:  If two values are same i have to assert true,if not i have to assert false

This is what i tried

```
expect(values).not.toBeDefined(values)
expect(values).toEqual(values);
expect(values).not.toBe(values)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get `values` separately using `.then()` chaining. `expect` statement by default resolves the promises that the methods return. You just have to use them in your expect statement. Here's how -

```
var archived_projects_before = element.all(by.css('a[ng-click="setCurrentGroup(tab)"]')).get(6);    
var archived_projects_before_1 = element.all(by.css('a[ng-click="setCurrentGroupproject(tab)"]')).get(6);

expect(archived_projects_before.getText()).toEqual(archived_projects_before_1.getText()); //Check for equality of values
```

The above `expect` statement passes if they both are equal, else it will throw the an error with following format-

> Expected 5 to equal 6

Similarly you can test for other conditions that you want to -

```
expect(archived_projects_before.getText()).toBeDefined(); //Check if the value is not undefined and should have a valid value
expect(archived_projects_before_1.getText()).toBeDefined(); //Check if the value is not undefined and should have a valid value

expect(archived_projects_before.getText()).not.toEqual(archived_projects_before_1.getText()); //Check for the inequality of values. This will throw error if the values passed are equal in terms of both type and value.
```

Hope it helps.